# Spring Boot Web Scraping With Selenium Inside Container

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver

In my Spring Boot backend application I'm also doing scrape with Selenium. I use Chrome Driver and I have added chromedriver to my application. How is scraping side done when I dockerize my spring boot application?